# Splitting strings with words from right based on limit

Tags: python, python-2.7, split, conditional-statements

I have this list, consisting of string of tags and weights:

```
 lst = ['rock 101071', 'pop 69159', 'alternative 55777', 'indie 48175',
        'electronic 46270', 'female vocalists 42565', 'favorites 39921', 
        'Love 34901', 'dance 33618', '00s 31432']
```

and I'm trying to convert that into tuples like:

```
[('rock ', '101071'), ('pop ', '69159'), ('alternative ', '55777'), ('indie ', '48175'), 
 ('electronic ', '46270'), ('female vocalists ', '42565'), ('favorites ', '39921'), 
 ('Love ', '34901'), ('dance ', '33618'), ('s ', '0031432')]
```

Here, each string is been split to tuple such that index 0 of each element is containing words except the last word and the element at index 1 contains the last word of the string.

---

For achieving this, my code is:

```
tags=[]
weights=[] 

for i in lst:       
    tag = ''.join([x for x in i if not x.isdigit()])
    tags.append(tag)
    weight = ''.join([x for x in i if x.isdigit()])
    weights.append(weight)
```

and then, if I do:

```
 print zip(tags, weights)
```

I get the desired result. But unfortunately some tags themselves consist in digits, like `00's` in `lst`.

How can I format `('00s ', '0031432')` correctely?

PS: As an alternative splitting method, `i.split("")` is not ideal, because some tags in the set have many words.

Comment: So you want to split off the last token of each string? And do you need the extra space on the tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use [`str.rsplit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rsplit) to split the string based on space with `maxsplit` as 1. For example:

```
>>> lst = ['rock 101071', 'pop 69159', 'alternative 55777', 'indie 48175', 'electronic 46270', 'female vocalists 42565', 'favorites 39921', 'Love 34901', 'dance 33618', '00s 31432']

>>> [s.rsplit(' ', 1) for s in lst]
[['rock', '101071'], ['pop', '69159'], ['alternative', '55777'], ['indie', '48175'], ['electronic', '46270'], ['female vocalists', '42565'], ['favorites', '39921'], ['Love', '34901'], ['dance', '33618'], ['00s', '31432']]
```

But this will be list of nested lists (which I think should be fine). But if it is must to have nested tuple as mentioned in the question, then you may type-cast the values to tuple as:

```
[tuple(s.rsplit(' ', 1)) for s in lst]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> lst = ['rock 101071', 'pop 69159', 'alternative 55777', 'indie 48175',
...         'electronic 46270', 'female vocalists 42565', 'favorites 39921', 
...         'Love 34901', 'dance 33618', '00s 31432']
>>> 
>>> [tuple(s.rsplit(maxsplit=1)) for s in lst]
[('rock', '101071'), ('pop', '69159'), ('alternative', '55777'), ('indie', '48175'), ('electronic', '46270'), ('female vocalists', '42565'), ('favorites', '39921'), ('Love', '34901'), ('dance', '33618'), ('00s', '31432')]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work even for tags with multiple words:

```
def processdata(lst):
    raw_tuples = [i.split() for i in lst]
    sani_tuples = [(' '.join(i[:-1]), i[-1]) for i in raw_tuples]
    return sani_tuples

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lst = ['rock 101071', 'pop 69159', 'alternative 55777', 'test multi word tag 101020']
    print(processdata(lst))
```

Output:

```
[('rock', '101071'), ('pop', '69159'), ('alternative', '55777'), ('test multi word tag', '101020')]
```

Comment: Good solution, but `rsplit` is better suited for the job, as in the other answer.